# list data.tables in memory and combine by row (rbind)

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, rbind

I have many data.tables in memory with names following a specific pattern (e.g.: RE_1, RE_2... CO_1, CO_2...). I want to bind them efficiently to get only two data.tables (RE and CO).

I tried:

```
RE <- rbindlist(ls(pattern = "RE"))
```

But I got the following error: "Error in rbindlist(ls(pattern = "RE")) : 
  Input to rbindlist must be a list of data.tables".

Is there a way to make such a "usable" list of data.tables (or data frames)?

Comment: I think you should use the built in function `tables`, otherwise you will be picking everything that matches RE from the global environment, including lists, data frames and etc. In other words, the correct way of doing this is `temp <- tables(mb = FALSE, silent = TRUE)$NAME;
rbindlist(mget(grep("RE", temp, value = TRUE)));
rbindlist(mget(grep("CO", temp, value = TRUE)))`

Comment: OK, nice! Maybe less intuitive than the @FlooO solution... But that's true I may have got some problems if I had other objects than data.tables following the same name pattern

Comment: It is less intuitive, but it will make sure you are extracting *only* `data.table`s from your environment.

Comment: should mention that if you can avoid it, you should be creating these tables as a list in the first place--e.g., `rbindlist(lapply(file_names_RE,fread))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
rbindlist(lapply(ls(pattern = "RE"),get))
```

Dont know if this is the most effective way but... It works.

`ls(...)` returns a vector with the names of your data.tables. Not the data.tables themself. `get` gets you the object by name.

You can also use

```
rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "RE")))
```